# How to split with more than a char?

Tags: c#, split

I want to split at spaces, newlines, and commas.

Here is where I split with the space char:

```
StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader("E:\\Lectures\\Fourth year\\2nd term\\IR\\Sections\\Files\\Files\\Document2.txt");
string doc = sr1.ReadLine();
string[] docArr = doc.Split(' ');
```

Answer (score 9):

You can pass in an array of chars.

```
string[] docArr = doc.Split(new char[]{' ', '\n', ','});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is also valid: `doc.Split(new []{' ','\n',','});`

Comment: Yeah, but I forget what version of the compiler that was introduced in, may not port backwards. That's why I said only "pretty sure"

Comment: @MartyDill: Would be even easier if you used the `params` overload :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Split(new char[] {'\n',',',' '});
```

Comment: ironically {'\n',',',''); is also the answer to the question "what would happen if i put an emoticon in a blender"

Comment: though please also close the curly brace, my cdo is killing me just looking at it :L

Comment: @RhysW I don't think that's irony. =)

Comment: typo guys give me a break, I was fixing it while you trampling all over my post.

Comment: sorry for pointing out the errors so the asker actually had correct code to use...

Comment: @Yatrix, is it not ironic to incorrectly use the word ironically? Therefore all use of the word irony must be ironic in some way or the other ;-)

Comment: I'm cursed with this terrible and unique affliction, sometimes the key I think I've pressed isn't or doesn't. I know this is a great failing and that my coping mechanism (it's called read and edit) is barely acceptable, but if you could find it in your hearts to make some allowance for this awful character defect, I would be so greatful.

Comment: See now you made me spell garaytful wrong! Stop picking on me. :D

Comment: XD didnt know youd spotted it dude remember - stack overflow is not a mindreader

:D

Comment: and also please tell me garaytful was you taking the michael and not how you think its spelt or i might just die a little inside

Comment: @TonyHopkinson the trick is "read and edit before submit" which is what we do, since you have to use a mouse to do so.

Comment: You do realise after a statement like that, any typos of your own will be gleefully pointed out? No pressure...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
 var str = @"123,456 789\r";

 //split using string.Split(params char[] separator)
 var arr = str.Split(char.Parse(" "), char.Parse("\n"), char.Parse(","));
```

Comment: missing a closing ) at the end of your last line of code char.parse(",")); it should be

Comment: @RhysW: Thanks - now I can remove my disclaimer :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [String.Split method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

Like this:

```
string[] docArr = doc.Split(new char[] {'\n', ',', ' ' });
```

Comment: there has to be a space between the two '' in this code or its an illegal character

Comment: @RhysW I am sorry you need to use the `' '`. My answer is changed

Comment: @RhysW you're coming dangerously close to exceeding your daily quota of posts.The number is 3 million and you have only 4 left.

Comment: trying to get as many posts as @jonskeet has rep, obviously, unfortunately his rep has found out how to asexually replicate and is growing exponentially

Comment: Actually, asking loads of questions will get you sorta-banned (it's a gradual wearing off, as opposed to insta-banned and perma-banned)

Comment: @jcolebrand, Yatrix and RhysW: is this related to my answer or is it something I don't be affraid of. To be honest I don't know where you all speaking about so if it is related to me, please explain what I am doing wrong.